# How can I know if the curator InterProcessSemaphoreMutex was re-acquired after it was lost?

Tags: java, mutex, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using the `InterProcessSemaphoreMutex` [curator recipe](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-lock.html) to ensure that my application process is always a singleton. The mutex can sometimes be lost because of transient network errors or application pausing (because of GC, for example). 
I am using a retry policy so that the process can make an attempt to reacquire the lock. I want my application process to exit if it is unable to re-acquire the lock within (say) 5 minutes.

The documentation for the recipe suggests that we can listen for ConnectStateChange events. The event LOST that indicates the connection to zookeeper has been lost and so the process lost the lock as well.
This way, the process can detect if it loses the lock.

How can the process check if it was successful in re-acquiring the lock? I can't find any method on the mutex that can give me this information. The suspiciously useful "isAcquiredInThisProcess" method doesn't really give me that information.

Comment: Do you mean you want the semaphore to be automatically re-acquired by curator? I don't think it's possible to re-acquire a semaphore without an explicit call from your application to InterProcessSemaphoreMutex#acquire whose return result will let you know whether the semaphore has been successfully acquired.

Comment: @Aeham I assumed that it the process will try to automatically reacquire the lock. The documentation around this seems a little thin. Or I am not searching in the right places!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by retryPolicy, some of the curator objects have a retry policy ([DistributedAtomicLong](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/distributed-atomic-long.html) for example).

I don't see how you use it with `InterProcessSemaphoreMutex`, but the InterProcessSemaphoreMutex has an `acquire(long time, TimeUnit unit)` method, using it with 5 minutes won't solve your problem?